# I wrote Python code, but I keep getting runtime errors

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):

        if not strs:
            return ""

        res = ""

        for i in range(len(strs[0])):
            for s in strs:
                if strs[0][i] != s[i] or i >= len(s):
                    return res
            res += strs[0][i]

        return res
```

I'm solving [LeetCode problome 14](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/), but the following code is wrong and an error appears:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
    if strs[0][i] != s[i] or i >= len(s):
Line 11 in longestCommonPrefix (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().longestCommonPrefix(param_1)
Line 35 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 45 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

What's wrong with my code?

I asked to ChatGPT 3.5 but his code was wrong too.

Comment: There are more values in `strs[0]` than in `strs`. You need to check if the index is out of bounds before you check the values `if i >= len(s) or strs[0][i] != s[i]`

Comment: There are more values in `strs[0]` than in `strs[i]` for some other `i`.  It never indexes into `strs` except with the fixed index `0` (but it does iterate over its values).

Comment: You need to bear in mind that the valid index range for a non-empty list of length N is -N to N-1

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, logic-wise. only wrong is when you are chosing string for reference ie you are chosing string at 0 - index. this is making your code fail

case where, string length at index 0 is greater than at other indexes , so by your code, it is looking for value at that index, it is not founding that and thus throwing this error.

eg usecase : `['str1', 's']`, for this input for index 1 of `str1` value it throw error.

to solve this chose the string which has minimum length as reference

thus your updated code should be

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):

        if not strs:
            return ""

        res = ""
        reference = min(strs, key=len) # get the word with minium length 
        for i in range(len(reference)):
            for s in strs:
                if strs[0][i] != s[i]: # removing index comparision part
# as max length of common prefix should be the minimum length of word among strs array
                    return res
            res += strs[0][i]

        return res
```